# Sagemaker Pipelines with Autopilot Step

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm looking to combine the Autopilot AutoML training and deployment step into a wider Pipeline using Sagemaker.

I can't find anything in the documentation around using AutoML with Pipelines.

Does anyone have any experience with trying something like this with Sagemaker?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe pipelines support AutoML, you can see a list of supported steps here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html

You could potentially add in a Lambda step and trigger an AutoML job from the lambda function. I'd also recommend rethinking the flow, since AutoML runs and trains using multiple algorithms. While it is great for exploration, it might not be the best for reusable pipelines.

Comment: Thanks - Is there an example of how to include the AutoML step as a Lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines don't support an AutoML step today. Check out this blog post which shows how to integrate AutoML into your Pipeline using Lambdas.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/move-amazon-sagemaker-autopilot-ml-models-from-experimentation-to-production-using-amazon-sagemaker-pipelines/

Particularly the example of how to launch AutoML in a Lambda function is here:

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/autopilot/sagemaker-autopilot-pipelines/start_autopilot_job.py

Answer (score 0):

You can now integrate [Sagemaker autopilot step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html#step-type-automl) into your pipeline [as per this example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/df6c76360e67283dea18e60cbda69ec490faa2f2/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/tuning-step/sagemaker-pipelines-tuning-step.ipynb):

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Sagemaker pipeline now only supports ensembling training mode of AutoML as a native pipeline step which you can refer to the [public doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html#step-type-automl) and [example notebook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/automl-step).